# Authenticity_token is missing in custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf-protection, authenticity-token

I have a controller where I have a custom action (not part of the RESTful set) to create an association object.

The `authenticity_token` is not added to the form, I assume this is because the action is not part of the RESTful set?

How would I add `authenticity_token` when it's not automatically added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "authenticity_token", form_authenticity_token %>
```

to your form.

You could make a helper for this:

```
def authenticity_token_tag
  hidden_field_tag "authenticity_token", form_authenticity_token 
end
```

then in your form you can just say

```
<%= authenticity_token_tag %>
```

Comment: That only outputs the `authenticity_token` as text.

Comment: Yes, just realised that and updated my answer - sorry :)